# count item of objects but with differents key values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with duplicates items, i want to count them with an array of objects, but my code doesn't work.

```
var array = ['far-picto_tout_compris','far-picto_tout_compris','far-picto_tout_compris',
'far-picto_sour','far-picto_sour', 'far-picto_serenite',
'far-picto_serenite','far-picto_serenite',];

var res = array.reduce((acc, val, index) => {
      acc.push({[val]: 1});
      return acc;
    }, []);
```

I want [{far-picto_tout_compris: 3}, ...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is to count the keys using an object (because it's convinient) and then transform the object into an array of objects.

```js
const array = [
  'far-picto_tout_compris',
  'far-picto_tout_compris',
  'far-picto_tout_compris',
  'far-picto_sour',
  'far-picto_sour',
  'far-picto_serenite',
  'far-picto_serenite',
  'far-picto_serenite',
];

const res = Object.entries(array.reduce((tmp, x) => {
  tmp[x] = (tmp[x] || 0) + 1;

  return tmp;
}, {})).map(([key, value]) => ({
  [key]: value,
}));

console.log(res);
```

---

One line alternative

```js
const array = [
  'far-picto_tout_compris',
  'far-picto_tout_compris',
  'far-picto_tout_compris',
  'far-picto_sour',
  'far-picto_sour',
  'far-picto_serenite',
  'far-picto_serenite',
  'far-picto_serenite',
];

const res = Object.entries(array
    .reduce((tmp, x) => (tmp[x] = (tmp[x] || 0) + 1, tmp), {}))
    .map(([key, value]) => ({
       [key]: value,
    }));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: your code can be simplified to `Object.values(array.reduce((tmp, x) => (
  tmp[x] ? tmp[x][x]++ : (tmp[x] = {[x]: 1}),  tmp), {}))`

Answer (score 0):

You could take a `Map` for counting and then render the wanted result.

```js
var array = ['far-picto_tout_compris','far-picto_tout_compris','far-picto_tout_compris', 'far-picto_sour','far-picto_sour', 'far-picto_serenite', 'far-picto_serenite','far-picto_serenite'],
    result = Array.from(
        array.reduce((map, value) => map.set(value, (map.get(value) || 0) + 1), new Map),
        ([key, count]) => ({ [key]: count })
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want this in an array?

```
    var array = ['far-picto_tout_compris','far-picto_tout_compris','far-picto_tout_compris','far-picto_sour','far-picto_sour', 'far-picto_serenite','far-picto_serenite','far-picto_serenite',];
    let object = {};

    for (element of array) {
       object[element] = object[element] !== undefined ? object[element] + 1 : 1;
    }

    // object === {"far-picto_tout_compris":3,"far-picto_sour":2,"far-picto_serenite":3}
```

Then you can user object.keys to iterate..

https://gomakethings.com/the-es6-way-to-loop-through-objects-with-vanilla-javascript/